# How would I sever a game from it's parent server?

Tags: emulation, zombies-ate-my-friends

I've been wanting to play the game 'Zombies Ate My Friends' but it has been fully dropped by it's parent company Glu. This means the servers have been closed so any APK gotten off the internet won't work.
Recently I unzipped an APK file for the game and I've been wondering, would it be possible to just disconnect the game from it's parent server? I have all of the files in the game so I should have the multiplayer connection file. I also just want to play the single player campaign so it wouldn't matter if I am connected to the server.

Comment: Are you sure the single player campaign does not communicate with the server?

Comment: I'm not sure. But even if it did, could one just remove server capabilities for the single player campaign? I know it's a long shot.